# google cache not getting updated

Tags: seo, browser-cache

My website's cache is not getting updated on google from last 5-6 months even though date stamp with cache keeps changing.
Here is link to [cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://paintcollar.com/shop).

In given link date shown is of 22nd April 2016 but the content is at least 5 months old.

Comment: What is you question exactly?

Comment: Google keeps cached copy of each web page that google's bot crawl which keeps updating depending on the number of times a page is crawled by google. in my case, website is being crawled by regularly but cached copy of pages is not being updated.  Please visit our website Paintcollar.com and its cached copy at http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://paintcollar.com. you can clearly see that contents(images and text) is entirely different.  images shown on cached page were there on the website 5 months ago. hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: That was clear, it is not clear what your question is... Are you asking "Why my website is not being updated" or "Is there something wrong with my website settings" or what else? Usually questions end up with a question mark!

Comment: Yes.. why my website is not being updated and what can i do to rectify it?.. Sorry for not making it clear earlier

Comment: Use fetch as googlebot in webmaster tools to see what googlebot sees. Cause /shop is redirected to /shop?page=1 for users but I couldnt see that happening for bots.

Answer (score 2):

To change the content shown in the snippet (or on the linked cached page), you'll first need to change the content on the actual (live) page.

**See more over at Google Webmaster Blog:**

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/url-removals-explained-part-ii-removing.html

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the info.  I don't want to remove the whole page. i just want to update the content of page. Do I have to still submit request for URL removal? Won't it harm my search traffic?

Comment: What you have to do is change something simple on the front page of the site (content, Image, etc), save the page upload it to your server so you know something is changed, then log into google Webmaster tools, and resubmit the site to be indexed, DO NOT request a URL removal.

Comment: I just noticed that if you view source for the site it is very simplistic ( view-source:http://paintcollar.com/ ) when compared to the cached version of the site. Does the site use an iframe or script to be displayed? Do you own the code or is it hosted by someone else?

Comment: Hi,  we own the site and we don't use the i-frame but its written in java script. Can this be an issue since its dynamic page??

Comment: Here are a few articles that may help your question:
https://www.seroundtable.com/google-content-hidden-dynamic-20653.html
 // 

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/l1uvr8wamic
 // 
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/dynamic-serving